# Error messages when I execute SQL Query in the Where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a SQL query using SQL Server Management Studio,
But, I faced errors in the Where statement.

Here `WHERE` clause of the SQL code:

```
   where 
       (case when 'All' in (select Items from CDB.dbo.Split (@a,','))
        then  innt.code **IS** NOT NULL
        else  innt.code in (select Items from CDB.dbo.Split (@a,',')) end) and
```

I get these error messages:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 90
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 92
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.

Can you guys please help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booleans are not a type in SQL Server.  So a `case` cannot return a boolean expression.

So, just use regular comparisons

```
where ('All' in (select Items from CDB.dbo.Split(@a, ',') and innt.code IS NOT NULL) or
      (innt.code in (select Items from CDB.dbo.Split(@a, ',') )
```